# What's wrong with association with user and emergency contact?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working on authentication part. Also, I am new to rails view part.
Here, I am trying to signup with required field but I am getting error message which is due to association between user and emergency contact. Can anyone suggest how to resolve it? Thanks in advance.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :emergency_contact, foreign_key: 'user_id'
end
```

**emergency_contact.rb**

```
class EmergencyContact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**registrations/new.html.erb**

```
<h2>Sign up form</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <h3>Emergency Contact</h3>
  <div>
    <%= f.fields_for :emergency_contact, EmergencyContact.new do |emergency_contact| %>
      <div>
        <%= emergency_contact.label :full_name %> <br />
        <%= emergency_contact.text_field :er_full_name %> <br />
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
   @user = User.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password,emergency_contact_attributes: [:er_full_name] )
  end
end
```

**Error message:**

```
 1 error prohibited this user from being saved: 
 Emergency contact user must exist
```

Comment: Can you post your controller code?

Comment: You are creating a new emergency contact but the new method is not associated with the user being created. its user_id is nil therefore it is requiring you a valid user_id.... the correct thing is that you use a build method so that both are associated. Example: `f.fields_for: emergency_contact, resource.build_emergency_contact do |` instead of `f.fields_for: emergency_contact, EmergencyContact.new do |`

Comment: @JesusAlfonsoPintoDelgado changed that line still getting same error message. Should I need to add anything else?

Comment: Please post your controller code

Comment: @JesusAlfonsoPintoDelgado I have added my users controller.

Comment: @CannonMoyer I have added my users controller.

Comment: Replace `EmergencyContact.new` in your view with `f.object.emergency_contacts.build` or in the controller's `new` action you can state `@user.emergency_contacts.build` and completely omit the `EmergencyContact.new` from your view.

Comment: @CannonMoyer thanks for your time, resolved by customizing devise registration controller.

Answer (score 1):

controller:

```
  def new
   @user = User.new
   @emergency_contact = @user.build_emergency_contact
  end
```

view:

```
<%= form.fields_for @emergency_contact do |emergency_contact_fields| %>
  <div>
    <%= emergency_contact_fields.label :full_name %> <br />
    <%= emergency_contact_fields.text_field :er_full_name %> <br />
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, I solved the problem. Need to change devise registration controller.